# Parent child JAXB Unmarshalling - Java

Tags: java, jaxb, unmarshalling

```
<data>
    <payment>
        <paymentitems>
            <paymentitem>
            </paymentitem>
            <paymentitem>
            </paymentitem>
        </paymentitems>
        <paymentitemdetails>
            <paymentitemdetail>
            </paymentitemdetail>
            <paymentitemdetail>
            </paymentitemdetail>
        </paymentitemdetails>
        <lineitems>
            <lineitem>
            </lineitem>
            <lineitem>
            </lineitem>
        </lineitems>
    </payment>
</data>
```

I want to unmarshal the above mentioned xml string. I am confused how can I start with this as this is nested and having parent child relationships.I have done the unmarshalling
for Single element xml which means if it is ... I am struggling to find a start here.

Comment: if you have xsds for this xml, then you can automatically generate java classes which will map to this xml. Lookup xjc compiler

Comment: I generated java classes by passing the XML request in the site and got the class files. http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/. Now I want to extract the data for the <payment></payment> element.

Answer (score 0):

**Singular Relationships**

There isn't anything special you need to do to map relationships.

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Data {

    private Payment payment;

}
```

**Collection Fields/Properties**

You will want to look at the `@XmlElementWrapper` annotation for mapping your collections since they have a grouping element:

```
 @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
 public class Payment {

    @XmlElementWrapper(name="paymentitems")
    @XmlElement(name="paymentitem")
    private List<PaymentItem> paymentItems;

}
```